# How to append to JS associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an existing multidimensional associative array with this structure. It has 3 elements. Each of the subarrays has 3 elements.

```
{"id":"723419","lat":33.217,"lon":-92.817,"dist":1437.15733534053},
{"id":"723424","lat":33.567,"lon":-91.717,"dist":1902.4556686060116},
{"id":"722447","lat":32.383,"lon":-94.717,"dist":2317.6870313059217},
```

I want to create another (temp) array with 3 elements, and loop through the array, adding an element to each subarray so that each subarray will have 4 elements:

```
{"id":"723419","lat":33.217,"lon":-92.817,"dist":1437.15733534053,"elev":abc},
{"id":"723424","lat":33.567,"lon":-91.717,"dist":1902.4556686060116,"elev":def},
{"id":"722447","lat":32.383,"lon":-94.717,"dist":2317.6870313059217,"elev":ghi},
```

so far, I've tried to loop through my temp array

```
 for (var i in tempArray) { //loop through locations returned with elevation data
     multiArray[i]['elev']=...
 }
```

and treated it as an object (even though I declared the multi array as an `Array()`

```
 for (var i in tempArray) { //loop through locations returned with elevation data
      multiArray.i.append(elev)=...
 }
```

Both ways, JS complains that `multiArray[i]` doesn't exist. From what I know about JS, this should work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are looping through tempArray but trying to access the multiArray. And your list is like this:-

[{"id":"723419","lat":33.217,"lon":-92.817,"dist":1437.15733534053},
{"id":"723424","lat":33.567,"lon":-91.717,"dist":1902.4556686060116},
{"id":"722447","lat":32.383,"lon":-94.717,"dist":2317.6870313059217}] ? For arrays use simple for loop not for in loop. for in loop is best for objects not arrays.

Comment: JavaScript is not PHP. Do not use `for .. in` to loop through arrays in JavaScript, it's the Wrong Thing (use a regular `for` loop from `i = 0` to `array.length` instead). Also, those are *objects*, not associative arrays. Whether you use `Array()` or `[]` to declare it does not make any technical difference, but you should always use `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made simple demo that has predefined values and then create another array that get it's value from the first array then add the new element `elev`

```
var arr = [{
    "id": "723419",
        "lat": 33.217,
        "lon": -92.817,
        "dist": 1437.15733534053
}, {
    "id": "723424",
        "lat": 33.567,
        "lon": -91.717,
        "dist": 1902.4556686060116
}, {
    "id": "722447",
        "lat": 32.383,
        "lon": -94.717,
        "dist": 2317.6870313059217
}];
var tempArray = new Array();
for (var item in arr) {    
    tempArray.push(arr[item]);
    tempArray[item]["elev"] = "value"; //write here your value
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/MSAND/)**

Comment: `for .. in` is not the proper way to iterate an array in JavaScript, because it lists any members that might have been added to the array prototype. Please use the correct form `for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)`.

Comment: Between ebram tharwat's and @pvnarula's answers, I figured it out. However, if the two arrays are the same length, does it matter which array I'm looping through? i still has the same slot in the array